# Loop to Delete Specific Files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have countless folders I need to access and delete the first 6 files within. Currently, I have a code to go into the folder, and delete each file one at a time. I can't seem to figure out how to create a loop to simplify this code.

```
FN_NIFTI = 'C: path';
funcdir = 'C: path'/folder';
FNruns = {'Folder 1', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 3', etc..};

for i=1:length(FNruns)
    delete(fullfile(FN_NIFTI,funcdir,FNruns{i},'*001.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(FN_NIFTI,funcdir,FNruns{i},'*002.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(FN_NIFTI,funcdir,FNruns{i},'*003.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(FN_NIFTI,funcdir,FNruns{i},'*004.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(FN_NIFTI,funcdir,FNruns{i},'*005.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(FN_NIFTI,funcdir,FNruns{i},'*006.nii'))
end
```

Keep in mind, the code above is copy/pasted several times. For example, I have another code below it such as:

```
ASL_NIFTI = 'C: path';
funcdir = 'C: path'/folder';
ASLruns = {'Folder 1', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 3', etc..};

for i=1:length(NWruns)
    delete(fullfile(ASL_NIFTI ,funcdir,ASLruns {i},'*001.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(ASL_NIFTI ,funcdir,ASLruns {i},'*002.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(ASL_NIFTI ,funcdir,ASLruns {i},'*003.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(ASL_NIFTI ,funcdir,ASLruns {i},'*004.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(ASL_NIFTI ,funcdir,ASLruns {i},'*005.nii'))
    delete(fullfile(ASL_NIFTI ,funcdir,ASLruns {i},'*006.nii'))
end
```

I appreciate the help! (with explanation for a beginner please)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by improving the for loop a bit.

```
for i = 1:length(targetFolder)
    for fileNr = 1:6
        delete(fullfile(targetFolder{i}, sprintf('*00%d.nii', fileNr)));
    end
end
```

The variable `targetFolder` should contain all the folders you want to delete files in. If theese folders selected in a special way you could just line them up:

```
targetFolder = { ...
   fullfile(FNrunsRootDir, FolderA), ...
   fullfile(FNrunsRootDir, FolderC), ...
   ...
   fullfile(ALSrunsRootDir, FolderX), ...
   fullfile(ALSrunsRootDir, FolderY), ...
   ...
};
```

If *all* the subfolders in each root folder should be picked you could use `dir` to get them

```
rootDirs = {FNrunsRootDir, ALSrunsRootDir, ...}

for iDir = 1:length(rootDirs)
    subDirs = dir(rootDirs{iDir});
    % Pick out all valid sub folders
    subDir = setdiff({subDir([subDir.isdir]).name}, {'.','..'});
    % Combine into full folder paths
    targetFolder = strcat(rootDirs{i}, filesep, subDir);

       %%%% FOR LOOP FROM ABOVE GOES HERE %%%%

end
```